# MongoDB: Using *NOT-dot* notation in sort

Tags: mongodb, sorting, syntax, mongodb-query

I'm having an issue with the Mongo **sort** on nested collection and Google search didn't help:

**Dot** notation works (returns first element from sorted collection):

```
db.myCollection.find().sort({ 'comments.Comment' : -1 })[0]
```

Array (**Not-dot**) notation doesn't work (always returns first element from un-sorted collection):

```
db.myCollection.find().sort({ "comments['Comment']" : -1 })[0]
```

For some business reasons I would like my app to be dynamic and handle spaces/pluses/and few more un-standard characters as the keys in the documents,

So far I was ok with it but sort **always** returns first (unordered) result if it can't understand the key which I want to sort on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put:

> *"For some business reasons I would like my app to be dynamic and handle spaces/pluses/and few more un-standard characters as the keys in the documents"*

Yeah, well bad luck it's **not valid** JSON notation, it may be **JavaScript** notation but that doesn't mean it's valid JSON. And the BSON spec derives from this fact.

You have **dot (.)** notation and **that is it**. So basically your condition is parsed as *"invalid"* and is ignored, hence no sorting is done how you expect.

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) issue with MongoDB if you believe this is important.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's one of those things that would be nice to have, but true -> it's not a valid json (if you look at it that way) and MongoDb tries to be as syntax-correct as possible and it's probably a good thing... Thanks!